# Eclipse IFile: Create not called when jar is deleted

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, file-exists, eclipse-api

I have a method that checks if a file exists then it deletes the file but will always create a new file (Jar file). I am using the **org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile** class for create and delete methods.

The code looks like this:

```
if(file != null){
   if(file.exists()){
       file.delete(true, monitor);
       system.out.println("File deleted");
     }
     system.out.println("File creation starting");
     file.create(stream, true, null);
     system.out.println("File created");
   }
```

**Problem:** When the jar file is existing, it calls the delete method but fails to call the other methods like the logs and the create method. But when I debug the whole process step by step it succeeds.

Example of scenarios for this issue

**Scenario 1:** Jar file is not in folder. It doesn't call the delete method. Calls the create method only. **Build is successful.**

**Scenario 2:** Jar file is already in the folder. It calls the delete method. Continues with the program without calling the create method or the sysout logs. **Build fails.**

**Scenario 3:** Jar file is already in the folder. Debug mode step by step. It calls the delete method and calls the create method. **Build is successful.**

May I know what am I missing? I tried to put a wait after the delete method and it succeeds but I don't think its the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: No i dont get any exception. It just skips the create method if delete method is called.

Comment: The only way the create could possibly be skipped after the delete is because of a exception. Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if one is being logged.

Comment: Hi greg, I already checked the .log file in the metadata directory but there are no exceptions/errors logged related to IFile.

Comment: Are you looking in the correct metadata - if you are running this from within Eclipse it will be in the test workspace, not the main Eclipse workspace. Otherwise use the Eclipse debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Yes its the correct workspace. Also as I said in the post, if I debug it step by step, it calls the delete then the create methods without any problems.

Comment: You could try surrounding this with a try-catch block and catching `Throwable` which should catch whatever is being thrown.